# Access violation writing location scanning input string

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

hello i have this error ": Access violation writing location 0x0000005000F90000."

my function
`

```
void inputCString(char *cstringValue, int min, int max) {
    int strsize = 0;
    char strlist[50] = { '\0' };
    while (scanf_s("%s", &strlist)) {
        strsize = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; strlist[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            strsize++;
        }
        if(strsize <= max && strsize >= min){
            *cstringValue = strlist;
            break;
        }
        else if(min == max){
            
            printf("ERROR: String length must be exactly %d chars:", min);
        }
        else {
            printf("ERROR: String length must be between %d and %d:", min,max);

        }

    }
}
```

`

my test function for it

`

```
void test06_inputCString(void)
{
    char cstringValue[7] = { '\0' };

    // Test explicit string length
    printf("TEST #6: - Instructions:\n"
           "1) Enter the word 'horse'   [ENTER]\n"  // too short
           "2) Enter the word 'chicken' [ENTER]\n"  // too long
           "3) Enter the word 'Beaver   '  [ENTER]\n"  // just right
           ":>");

    // You may want to comment the next line if you have not yet created the inputCString function:
    inputCString(cstringValue, 6, 6);

    printf("////////////////////////////////////////\n");
    printf("TEST #6 RESULT: ");
    printf("%s (expected result: Beaver)\n", cstringValue);
    printf("////////////////////////////////////////\n\n");
}
```

`

this code should get input from user then check if the input string size is within range (min , max) and return value from pointer *cstringValue but it dosent work

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile.  Are you compiling with warnings disabled?  Don't do that.

Comment: thank you . what is the problem with my code?

Comment: Enable warnings in your compiler and it will tell you.

Comment: it is already enabled and it  gives me error in run time

Comment: Are you looking at the compiler warnings?  If your compiler is not warning about this code, you must have its warnings disabled or you're not reading the output.  You can Google about how to enable warnings and errors in whatever compiler you're using.

Comment: thank you i checked it and its enabled and as i said i get the error in runtime

Comment: Time to change to a better compiler then.  Any compiler which compiles this code is misconfigured or defective.

Comment: That's too strong, @JohnZwinck.  The code is non-conforming, but lots of C compilers will accept it.  However, those that are any good will certainly emit warnings that should clue in the user about where to look for issues.

Comment: @SeagullSea `scanf_s("%s", &strlist)` is bad.  Enable all compiler warnings and review `scanf_s()` documentation.